# Why is there no set of all groups?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory

The texts speak of the collection of all groups as a "class". Can someone clarify what it means to be a class, how it is different from a set and why we cannot look at the set of all groups, and instead must deal with classes.

Comment: Note that this problem is an artifact of ZFC set theory. It may not be a true problem from a conceptual or philosophical standpoint. It is merely that the axioms of ZFC are incompatible with the existence of sets that have some of its elements in bijection with the universe. There are other foundations that do not face this problem.